# android SQLite data removed when close activity

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to save chat history to use it later. I save the chat history by button click, and I can read it correctly by clicking on another button within the same activity. But when I close the activity or close the app and then open the activity that must shows the chat history, there is no data at all. when I write again and try to read the history, it just returns the new chat. 
Here is my code where I define the database:

```
public class ChatDatabaseHelp extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    static String DATABASE_NAME;
    static int VERSION_NUM=1;
    public static String KEY_ID="key_id",KEY_MESSAGE="message";
    public static String TABLE_NAME="messages";
    public ChatDatabaseHelp(Context ctx)
    {
        super(ctx,DATABASE_NAME,null,VERSION_NUM);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String SQL="CREATE TABLE messages(key_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,message TEXT NOT NULL)";
        db.execSQL(SQL);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

And here is where I read and write the chat:

```
public class ChatWindow extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText t_send;
    Button send;
    ChatAdapter messageAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    ChatDatabaseHelp helper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    ArrayList<String> list;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_window);
        t_send=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        list= new ArrayList<String>();
        send=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        messageAdapter=new ChatAdapter(this);
        listView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
         helper=new ChatDatabaseHelp(this);
        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
                ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
                cv.put(helper.KEY_MESSAGE,t_send.getText().toString());
                db.insert(helper.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);


                list.add(t_send.getText().toString());
                t_send.setText("");
                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });

    }

    public void onfff(View view) {
        db=helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("select * from messages "  , null);
        System.out.println("hiii3ii"+cursor.getCount());
        while ((cursor.moveToNext())) {
            list.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("message")));
            messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private class ChatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public ChatAdapter(Context ctx){
            super(ctx,0);
        }
        public int getCount()
        {
           return list.size();
        }
        public String getItem(int position)
        {
            return list.get(position);
        }
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater=ChatWindow.this.getLayoutInflater();
            View result=null;
            if(position%2==0){
                result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_row_ingoing,null);
                TextView message=(TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.message_text_in);
                message.setText(getItem(position));}
            else{
                result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_row_outgoing,null);
                TextView message=(TextView)result.findViewById(R.id.message_text_out);
                message.setText(getItem(position));}


            return result;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        db.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: when is `onfff` called? It overwrites the `db` variable, which might mess with your insert call

Comment: it is called when user click on button  to read the history, but unfortunately it reads nothing when reopen the app

Comment: DATABASE_NAME isn't null is it?

Comment: 1) Move the code in `onfff` into another method with no parameters. 2) call new method from the `onfff` method and 3) call the new method immediately after the line `list= new ArrayList<String>();`. This would populate the list from the DB.

Comment: the problem is that the data in db seems to be overwritten every time I open the chat window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you call read database method in chatWindow class in onCreate method..

```
onfff() //above define this method call in onCreate()
```

Comment: the problem is that the data in db seems to be overwritten every time I open the chat window

Comment: check your db file the insert every time insert when chat window call.